# Socket cleaning

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipc

I am a bit confused by unix sockets (TCP local)

I have a **server** and a **client**:

- **client** sends some information  to server by sockets (using `send`)
  many times
- **server** prints this data (**server** calls `recv` to receive it).

The problem is that **server** prints not only the last information which was sent by **client**, but some old info (sometimes *corrupted*) from this **client** too, so I suppose that socket somehow *accumulates all the previous data which was written to it* by **client**.

How can **server** receive only the last data from **client**? Should I clean up the socket somehow, or I should close it all the time and create new (pretty bad solution) ?

Comment: Could you post the code? Keept it an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) though!

Comment: It can not. Exception is UDP with buffer overflow, but it anyway does what you want to avoid

Comment: TCP connection creates a data stream without explicit boundaries. The data boundaries are for the application to define. Your application must be prepared to do partial receive operation and be able to detect when it has received complete data. The meaning of this is that it may require more than one call to the recv function to receive the complete data sent by the peer.

Comment: Bet you its a missing memset on the recv buffer.

Comment: It sounds like you're not properly using the return value of `recv()` to know how many bytes were received on that call. The received data is not a null-terminated string, so you can't call `printf()` on it unless you add the `'\0'`.

Comment: @thuovila Calling memset() on the recv() buffer is literally just a waste of time. You only have to know how much of it was received, which recv() tells you.

Comment: @EJP I agree. Still, in some cases it can help (or move the problem elsehwrere...) Its difficult to say without seeing any code, but this sounded like Ninja Turtle was using some string.h functions or printfs on the buffer. Using the return value is surely the correct and best way to deal with input, but somehow people insist on finding other ways.

Comment: @EJP [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262998/error-communicating-a-c-server-and-a-java-client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262998/error-communicating-a-c-server-and-a-java-client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP sockets are stream sockets.
This means all data you send is treated not as a sequence of messages, but as a sequence of bytes. The bytes are received in order, without additions or omissions, but not necessarily in the same chunks.

For example, if your client calls `send` 3 times, with 1000 bytes each time, you can't tell how many times `recv` will return data. It may return 3 times, 1000 bytes each, or just once with 3000 bytes, or theoreticaly even 3000 times with 1 byte each time.

Comment: +1 on what ugoren just said. You need to check the return value from recv() to determine how many bytes you acutally got.  The biggest mistake many socket programmers make is assuming that "recv()" will return as many bytes as was passed to "send()".

Answer (score 1):

Image the bytes send/received are placed in a queue (the internal buffer). If you call `send()` two times, sending 10 bytes each time, there will be 20 bytes in the buffer. When the other side calls `recv()` it will take out a number of bytes from that queue and place them in  the array passed. How many bytes? Up to the available (20), or less.

For example, if you call

```
   nb =  recv(socket, arr, 15,...);
```

then only 15 bytes will be consumed (presumably your array `arr` has this length), they will be copied into `arr`, `nb` will be 15, and in the internal buffer we are left with 5 bytes.

If instead we'd call

```
   nb =  recv(socket, arr, 100,...);
```

then the 20 bytes would be copied into `arr`, `nb` would be 20, and  the internal buffer would be empty.

This shows you that:

- `send()`/`recv()` calls are **not** in one-to-one correspondence
- you must always check the `recv` return (`nb`) to know how many bytes were read
- you cannot know which bytes were sent in each `send()` call. The delimitation of "messages" is up to you
- you are not reading messages, nor strings (null-terminated char arrays), you are just reading bytes. Then, you cannot just call `printf("%s",arr)` to see the received bytes

Answer (score 1):

1. tcp is stream protocol;
2. check the return value of send and recv, make sure error has been properly handled;
3. check what you print is what you send, check send and recv buffer in binary content and length.

Make sure what you send at the sender side is what you will get at the receiver side.

And a piece of code is well appreciated for further analysis.